# Using Bool in haskell with other numerical types

Tags: haskell

Is there any 'elegant' way to use Bool type in numerical expressions ?
My current solution is using `fromIntegral.fromEnum` but is seems long.
Example:

```
lst::[(Double, Double)]
lst = [(1, -1 * (odd i)) | i<- [1..]]
```

Comment: This is an odd question because it does not indicate why True should mean 1 and False should mean 0. You can simply assign `fromIntegral.fromEnum` to a shorter name, but I suspect you're looking for alternative approaches, in which case I need to understand why Bools are being interpreted as numbers.

Comment: That particular example would be better written `lst = cycle [(1,-1), (1,0)]`, at least for most purposes, so it's not really a good example.

Comment: How about `if even i then 0 else -1`? Or ``i `mod` (-2)``?

Comment: For some purposes, `map ((,) 1) $ iterate (\x -> (-1) - x) (-1)` may be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the general purpose of interpreting Bools as Integers from the question, so I am only answering to the example given. Let me know how I can expand my answer.

```
lst::[(Double, Double)]
lst = [(1, -1 * (odd i)) | i<- [1..]]
```

The first element of the tuple is always 1, so this example can be simplified.

```
lst :: [Double]
lst = [-1 * (odd i) | i<- [1..]]
```

For the reader, `odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool`, and `fromEnum True = 1; fromEnum False = 0`.

Under the `fromEnum` interpretation, `lst` is an infinite list of `-1` interspersed with zeroes. How else can we implement this list?

```
intersperse 0 (repeat (-1))
```

Then how do we get back the desired tuples? Apply `fmap (1,)` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a standard way. You can write your own, of course:

```
enumToNum :: (Enum e, Num n) => e -> n
enumToNum = fromIntegral . fromEnum
```

The existence of this and similar functions really points to the silly nature of the `Enum` class.

Answer (score 1):

Package `Foreign.Marshal.Utils` contains `fromBool` function with the following definition:

```
-- |Convert a Haskell 'Bool' to its numeric representation
--
fromBool       :: Num a => Bool -> a
fromBool False  = 0
fromBool True   = 1
```

While I don't recommend to import this package for `fromBool` alone, you can copy it into your code.

By the way, good way to discover functions by type in the standard library is [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Num+a%3D%3EBool-%3Ea).